# Timeout in an Activity Function of Azure Durable Functions

Tags: node.js, azure, settimeout, azure-durable-functions

In my activity function I am doing this

```
do {
     await timeout(500);
} while (await getStatus() === false);
```

where,

```
function timeout(ms) {
      return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
```

`getStatus()` is a function that does a `get` request to see if process in other service is complete or not and returns `true` or `false` based on this.

I need my activity function to wait before the process in other service is complete. But activity function execution by default is limited to 5 minutes.
my `getStatus()` can take more than 2-3 hours or more based on different scenarios to return `true`.

What can I do here? Any advice?

Comment: can't you use then callback of promise ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of options:

**Option A: Use Monitor pattern + Rewind**

Could you split out the `getStatus` code to another Activity Function instead? If yes, then assume the following:

1. `ActivityFunction_A` - contains code before the do-while loop that is polling with `getStatus()`
2. `ActivityFunction_B` - contains the code that polls for `getStatus` with [maximum execution time of 10 minutes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#consumption-plan).
3. `ActivityFunction_C` - contains code after the `getStatus` returns `TRUE`

You can now orchestrate the workflow sequence

```
ActivityFunction_A => ActivityFunction_B => ActivityFunction_C
```

using the [Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-monitor) pattern.

Since any one of the Activity Functions could fail or timeout and there are potential side-effects of executing each activity function, you should also use the [Rewind](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-instance-management#rewinding-instances-preview) feature  (currently in preview) to rewind and replay only starting from the first failed Activity Function in the sequence.

**Option B: Use App Service Plan**

If your workflow does not really need to scale out to a lot of instances dynamically, you can migrate your Functions to an [App Service Plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#app-service-plan) with [AlwaysOn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#always-on) turned on.