# How to run an app that running more than 10 minutes using azure function?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, timer-trigger

I run an app that ran for about an hour each day in a specific time, at first I thought about using a regular app service (WebJobs) that works regularly but after checking the costs I decided it was a lot and maybe there is another way to run the app.

By the way, the app is a scraper that collects data from websites.

I tried to use the azure function but unluckily the function running 10 minutes at most as a consumption plan and change to app service I actually go back to the first solution.

settings in host.json file: (Trying to change to biggest timeout there is an error)

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "functionTimeout": "00:10:00"
}
```

**Application details:**

Console application  - output console

Debug\Release -  size up to 20MB

Running time - about an hour, once a day.

Using Azure SQL server + DB (500 MB)

**I would be very happy if someone had a more efficient and cheaper solution?**

Comment: Durable functions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview.

Comment: As far as I know, if we use consumption plan of Azure function the maximum timeout is 10 minutes. But as a suggestion, is it possible to separate your function to several part(several function with consumption plan) and trigger them one by one ?

Comment: Durable functions - each activity time out is 10 minutes and you can use multiple activities a s per your need

Comment: Please, can you share the example of how to implement this solution?

Comment: @ISTech, I think this link might be useful to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53864209/timeout-in-an-activity-function-of-azure-durable-functions

Comment: https://mikhail.io/2018/12/making-sense-of-azure-durable-functions/

Answer (score 0):

[Azure Container Instances](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/container-instances/) with [Azure SQL in the serverless tier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-serverless).